# What are the "thirteen covenants made upon" circumcision?

Tags: brit-milah, mishna, tractate-nedarim

What are the "thirteen covenants made upon" circumcision?

My question came from,
"Rabbi Ishmael says:  Great is circumcision, since thirteen covenants were made upon it." https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.31b.8?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Torah it says the word bris 13 times (in the chapter commanding it to Abraham)

See halacha 9 in [chapter 3 in the Rambam's laws of circumcision](http://www.chabad.org/932330/)

> thirteen covenants were established with Abraham, our Patriarch, with regard to circumcision:
>
> 1. "I will place My **covenant** between Me and you" [Genesis [17:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.2?lang=bi)],
> 2. "And I, behold, My **covenant** is with you" [ibid[.:4],](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.4?lang=bi)
> 3. "I will establish My **covenant** between Me and you" [ibid.:[7](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.7?lang=bi)],
> 4. "For an eternal **covenant**" [ibid.],
> 5. "And you shall observe My **covenant**" [ibid.:[9](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.9?lang=bi)],
> 6. "This is My **covenant** which you shall observe" [ibid[.:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.10?lang=bi)],
> 7. "It will be a sign of the **covenant**" [ibid.:[11](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.11?lang=bi)],
> 8. "My **covenant** will be in your flesh" [ibid.:[13](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.13?lang=bi)],
> 9. "For an eternal **covenant**" [ibid.],
> 10. "He will have nullified My **covenant**" [ibid.:[14](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.14?lang=bi)],
> 11. "And I will establish My **covenant** with Him" [ibid.:[19](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.19?lang=bi)],
> 12. "For an eternal **covenant**" [ibid.],
> 13. "And I will establish My **covenant** with Isaac" [ibid.:[21](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.21?lang=bi)]

---

Talmud [Nidarim 31b](https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.31b.8)

> **Rabbi Yishmael says**: So **great is** the mitzva of **circumcision that thirteen covenants were sealed with regard to it**, for the word covenant appears thirteen times in the biblical passage that discusses circumcision (Genesis, [chapter 17](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.17.2?lang=bi)).
>   ([Tosefot and the Ran](https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.31b.8/he/William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic?with=Commentary&lang=bi))

Comment: Why hasn't this become the accepted answer yet?@ninamag, why don't you reward hazoriz for his great work!